# Smaller number is greater than bigger number

Tags: javascript

In my JS, I'm doing a check to see if one number is greater than the other. I'm attaching the image of Chrome DevTools:

[image]

As you can see here, the code has made it inside the `if statement`. On the right, in the Watch, you can see `amount = "3.00"` and `available = "261.60"`.

What would cause the smaller number to be greater than the bigger number?

Comment: You are comparing a `string` to a `string` in which the expression `amount > available` evaluates to `true`. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are are comparing strings. In the code you are calling `parseFloat`, which is the right idea, but it's followed by `toFixed()`. `toFixed()` returns a string.

```js
console.log(typeof parseFloat("3.00").toFixed(2))
```

You need to make sure you're comparing numbers. An easy way is:

```
if(+amount > +available)
```

Alternatively, don't call `toFixed()` until it's time to display the number.